# Notification icon always the same, even when Liferea has new items

Tags: unity, notification, liferea

As you can see on this screenshot, the icon circled in red is always the same, whether Liferea has zero new items (left side), or has new items (right side).

[image: Liferea notification]

Why not have different icons depending on whether there are new items or not?

Is it:

1. intended?
2. something to configure?
3. a bug on my system only?
4. a bug for everybody?

EDIT: Since it is a bug, I filled [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/liferea/+bug/803760).

Comment: i think that the Messaging Indicator only changes when the software has support for it, i beiieve liferea doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2):

One of the design decisions in the creation of the indicator menus was to have constant icons, rather than changing ones.  In some versions, indicator-messaging will have a colour change when it detects new items, although this will not necessarily be present at login, depending on the interaction between the messaging provider and indicator-messages.

When a user opens the messaging menu, for any reason, the colour is adjusted to the base colour, even when the user has not viewed messages in all available applications: this allows the user to tell the system they are aware there are pending messages, and not be reminded to check again until more new messages arrive.

In the special case of liferea, there are some interaction issues related to parsing large numbers of feeds that can cause indicator-messages to be confused about the status.

Comment: I understand the design design you described. Too bad Liferea does not comply with this design: The user is never alerted of a newly arrived message, even if he hasn't opened this menu for ages. Colour never changes. I have 9 feeds, is it a large number?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to switch to [Feed Indicator](http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator/).