# RSS reader that integrates with Unity's messaging menu?

Tags: unity, rss

Right now I use Liferea, its problem is that the messaging icon [does not change when there is a new message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51235):

[image]

Is there an RSS reader that integrates better in Unity? My only requirement is:

- When there is a new message, it should be visible (for instance different colour) without having to click the envelope to check inside the menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Feed Indicator](http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator/)

[OmgUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/rss-indicator-applet-feed-indicator-fixes-browser-opening-bug/) have several web-blogs raving about this particular RSS indicator.

Looks promising.

[image]

Comment: I have become addicted to Feed Indicator, it is simple and great! By the way, feeds URLs are saved in .config/feedindicator/feeds.cfg

Answer (score 2):

Another useful RSS notification indicator is "Rss-Aware":

[image]

You can see more about it and installation from [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/rss-aware-puts-feed-updates-on-your-panel) link.

Comment: The official website http://freelanzer.com/rss-aware/index.html says "For an enhanced version check out Feed Indicator".